# Laravel 5.6 ajax ----

Tags: ajax, laravel

Hello I have an ajax request to retrieve the list of products. the request not well knowing that my table produced is connected with a color table
  table Product [id, name, imgs, color_id]
  table color [id, name, code]

how can i get the color code via ajax:

Here is part of my code:

```
    $('#product1').on('change', function(e) {

        var product_id = e.target.value;

        // Ajax Products Color
        if(product_id > 0) {
            $.get('/2c/ajax-compare?product_id=' + product_id, function(data) {

                $('#productProperty1').empty();
                $.each(data, function(index, prodObj) {
                    if(index == 0)
                    {
                        var square = '<a class="btn compare d-block mb-3 active-item">Compare<img class="pl-2 img-fluid" src="{{ asset('/asstes/images/bleu_active.png' ) }}" alt=""></a>';     
                        var image = '<img class="img-fluid mb-3" src="{{ asset('') }}'+prodObj.imgs+' " alt="">';
                    }

                    //var color = '<p>'+prodObj.color_id+'</p>';
```

// here i want to get the color code "prodObj.color_id"

```
                    $('#productProperty1').append(square, image);
                })
            })
        }

        else {

            $('#productProperty1').empty();
            var square = '<a class="btn compare d-block mb-3">Compare<img class="pl-2 img-fluid" src="{{ asset('/asstes/images/white_desactive.png' ) }}" alt=""></a>';
            var image = '<img class="img-fluid mb-3" src="{{ asset('/asstes/images/products/phones/default.png' ) }}" alt="">';

            $('#productProperty1').append(square, image);
        }

    });
```

Comment: *"here i want to get the color code "prodObj.color_id""* - Is that not working in some way?  What specifically is the problem?

Comment: Post your controller code also.